# move the animation from an Animation<TextureRegion> into another Libgdx

Tags: animation, libgdx

I would need to know how to move the contents of an Animation  into another.

```
 animation1 = new Animation;
 animation2 = new Animation; 
 index = 0;
 tempFrames = TextureRegion.split(xxx, xxx.getWidth() / 4, xxx.getHeight() / 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                tempAnimationFrames[index] = tempFrames[j][i];
                index++;
            }
        }
 animation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(1f / 8f, tempAnimationFrames);
```

How do I move the animation animation1 in animation2?

Comment: Unclear what you wanf. Just to duplicate the animation into another instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier than you think... I've got the same problem, you already declared animation2 so you only have to write :

```
animation2 = animation1;
```

Comment: Only this? Are you sure?

Comment: That's not copying the object, only the reference. But since the question is unclear, maybe that's what the OP wants?